# Yes/No checkbutton for bool attribute in a GUI to manage a list of objects

Tags: python, user-interface, checkbox, tkinter, boolean

For this gui I have five objects: Full name, Contact info, Desired Language, Difficulty level, and Experience with the language. My design for this assignment is that it's a simple 'Foreign Language Bookstore Request Manager' in which I can add, edit and delete requests for foreign language books.

I want the first four objects to be Entry fields and then the fifth (experience) to be a checkbox, for this data attribute I want to make it a bool representing yes/no state for the question of whether one has experience with the language they are requesting.

From my textbook and previous examples I was able to make a basic y/n checkbox, however it appears at the top of my window and I am stuck on how to write it so that the experience data attribute is a check button for the bool attribute rather than an Entry form and that whatever is selected (yes or no/whether it is true or false) appears when I use a *str* method to display each attribute's value using ListboxSelect.

When I have tried to separate the fifth attribute from the rest so that it is a checkbox rather than Entry form, I cannot run my program, and in trying to create the bool attribute I ran into errors as well and was unsure whether I need to fix the bool attribute first or the checkbox, whether they go hand in hand, etc

My questions are: 
1) Am I using the correct formatting to create the y/n checkbox for the bool attribute? 
2) How do I write the checkbox so that it appears next to the experience label and is not an Entry form as it is currently written?

I apologize if this is woefully stupid to ask, however I have spent 7 hours trying to troubleshoot these issues and haven't figured out what I am doing wrong and how to correct and add what is necessary to round out this program.

Unrelated to the check button, with the ListboxSelect widget, it is showing the object at the address I am looking for, but not actually displaying what I had thought I had written which would show:
'Full Name: , Contact info: , Language: , Difficulty: , Experience with language: (then here would be the answer to the checkbox for the boolean attribute which I haven't figured out yet)' in the Book Requests section of my program. I am including a picture of my program and current problems as well as some of the code. [does not display what I had thought I had written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1w8k.png)

```
import tkinter
import request

class Application:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__requests = []
        self.__selected_index = 0
        self.__selected_request = None

        self.__window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.__window.title('Foreign Language Bookstore Request Manager')

        self.__full_name = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.__contact_info = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.__language = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.__difficulty = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.__experience = tkinter.StringVar()

        self.cb_var1 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.cb_var2 = tkinter.IntVar()

        self.cb_var1.set(0)
        self.cb_var2.set(0)

        self.cb1 = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.__window, \
                                       text='Yes', variable=self.cb_var1)
        self.cb2 = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.__window, \
                                       text='No', variable=self.cb_var2)

        self.cb1.pack()
        self.cb2.pack()



        self.build_input_frame('Full Name: ', self.__full_name)
        self.build_input_frame('Contact info (phone, email): ', self.__contact_info)
        self.build_input_frame('Desired language: ', self.__language)
        self.build_input_frame('Difficulty level 1- beginner, 2- intermediate, 3- advanced: ', self.__difficulty)
        self.build_input_frame('Experience with language? ', self.__experience)

        frame = tkinter.Frame(self.__window)
        self.__add_button = tkinter.Button(frame, text='Add Request',
            anchor=tkinter.W, command=self.add_request)
        self.__add_button.pack(side='left')
        self.__save_button = tkinter.Button(frame, text='Save Request',
            anchor=tkinter.W, command=self.save_request, state=tkinter.DISABLED)
        self.__save_button.pack(side='left')
        self.__delete_button = tkinter.Button(frame, text='Delete Request',
            anchor=tkinter.W,
            command=self.delete_request, state=tkinter.DISABLED)
        self.__delete_button.pack()
        frame.pack()

        frame = tkinter.Frame(self.__window)
        label = tkinter.Label(frame, text='Book Requests')
        self.__requests_list = tkinter.Listbox(frame, width=80,
            selectmode=tkinter.SINGLE)

        self.__requests_list.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.select_request)
        label.pack()
        self.__requests_list.pack()
        frame.pack()

    def build_input_frame(self, label, textvariable):
        """Build the top frames of the window for being able to enter data."""
        frame = tkinter.Frame(self.__window)
        label = tkinter.Label(frame, text=label, width=50, anchor=tkinter.W)
        entry = tkinter.Entry(frame, textvariable=textvariable, width=30)
        label.pack(side='left')
        entry.pack(side='right')
        frame.pack()

    def add_request(self):
        """Get the values from the bound variables and create a new Request."""
        r = request.Request(self.__full_name.get(), self.__contact_info.get(),
            self.__language.get(), self.__difficulty.get(),
                            self.__experience.get())
        self.__requests.append(r)

        self.__requests_list.insert(tkinter.END, str(r))

    def select_request(self, event):
        """Get the Request at the index selected, and set the Entry fields
           with its values."""
        # Get the current selection from the Listbox. curselection() returns
        # a tuple and we want the first item
        # Get the current selection from the Listbox. curselection() returns
        # a tuple and we want the first item
        current_selection = self.__requests_list.curselection()
        if current_selection:
            self.__selected_index = current_selection[0]

            # Grab the Request object from self.__request at that index
            self.__selected_request = self.__requests[self.__selected_index]

            # Use it's values to set the StringVars
            self.__full_name.set(self.__selected_request.get_full_name())
            self.__contact_info.set(self.__selected_request.get_contact_info())
            self.__language.set(self.__selected_request.get_language())
            self.__difficulty.set(self.__selected_request.get_difficulty())
            self.__experience.set(self.__selected_request.get_experience())

            # Make sure the Save button is enabled
            self.__save_button.config(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
            self.__delete_button.config(state=tkinter.NORMAL)


    def delete_request(self):
        """Remov the Request at the index selected then set the Entry fields
           to empty values."""
        if 0 <= self.__selected_index < len(self.__requests):
            del self.__requests[self.__selected_index]
            self.__requests_list.delete(self.__selected_index)

            # Call the method to deselect the item, clear Entry fields, and
            # disable buttons.
            self.after_selected_operation()

    def save_request(self):
        """Set the selected Request's fields and then persist its __str__
           representation to the Listbox."""
        self.__selected_request.set_full_name(self.__full_name.get())
        self.__selected_request.set_contact_info(self.__contact_info.get())
        self.__selected_request.set_language(self.__language.get())
        self.__selected_request.set_difficulty(self.__difficulty.get())
        self.__selected_request.set_experience(self.__experience.get())

        # Listbox widgets don't have a way of updating an item in place. So
        # We'll delete the item at a particular index and then add it
        self.__requests_list.delete(self.__selected_index)
        self.__requests_list.insert(self.__selected_index,
            str(self.__selected_request))

        # Call the method to deselect the item, clear Entry fields, and
        # disable buttons.
        self.after_selected_operation()

    def after_selected_operation(self):
        """Clear the selected index, request, and disable buttons."""
        self.__selected_index = -1
        self.__selected_request = None

        self.__full_name.set('')
        self.__contact_info.set('')
        self.__language.set('')
        self.__difficulty.set('')
        self.__experience.set('')

        # Make sure the Save and Delete buttons are disabled
        self.__save_button.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
        self.__delete_button.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
```

Comment: how do you run your script? when I run it, I get a blank window

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Checkbutton`, it is better to use `Radiobutton` here, as you offer a yes/no option. You could use a `Checkbutton`, but it's more efficient to only offer a single one in that case. Then you can also implement the program structure you want.

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk


class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        # This is better practice when using Tkinter windows 
        # as this is a true OOP GUI implementation
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.boolean_var = tk.BooleanVar()
        self.option_yes = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Yes", variable=self.boolean_var,
                                         value=True, command=self.callback)
        self.option_no = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="No", variable=self.boolean_var,
                                        value=False, command=self.callback)
        self.option_yes.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.option_no.grid(row=0, column=1)

    def callback(self):
        print self.boolean_var.get()


Window().mainloop()
```

This approach also prevents both Yes and No from being selected simultaneously, and is somewhat more memory efficient as you only have to use a single `BooleanVar` object. As for your layout problems, it is quite difficult to troubleshoot with the code you have provided. However, if you need to create a more complicated layout with more than ten widgets, I recommend using the `grid` geometry manager, as it's easier to manage your layout and add more widgets later on. A good explanation and refernce for this geometry manager can be found [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm). I have found it very useful in the past.